# make whole blogger post preview clickable

Tags: javascript, blogger

on my website www.beatmushroom.com which is running on the blogger platfrom I have small previews of my posts on the home page. To get to the full post you have to click on the title.  I would like to be able to click anywhere on the post preview (thumbnail and text) and it take me to the post. I was thinking there may be some way to do this with javascript.

In the source code on the main page a post consists of this:

```
    <div class="date-outer">


    <div class="date-posts">

    <div class='post-outer'>
    <div class='post hentry'>
    <a name='366770510419642006'></a>
    <h2>
    <a href='http://www.beatmushroom.com/2012/05/logic-we-get-high.html'>Logic - We Get High</a>
    </h2>
    <div class='post-header'>
    <div class='post-header-line-1'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-366770510419642006'>
    <span class="tags">Rap</span><br>
    <img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qkVnjpTBMjY/T78PmQDUAvI/AAAAAAAAAKA/cUEMjJQ3w5s/s1600/logic.jpg">Here is a new one check it out logic has some good chilled tracks this has got a pretty old school feel to it. I am adding the blog to technorati. Technorati code: 886BP6K6GWA7<br>
    <div style='clear: both;'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='jump-link'>
    <a href='http://www.beatmushroom.com/2012/05/logic-we-get-high.html#more' title='Logic - We Get High'>&#9834; Listen Here &#187;</a>
    </div>
    <div class='post-footer'>
    <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-1'><span class='post-author vcard'>
    </span>
    <span class='post-timestamp'>
    </span>
    <span class='post-comment-link'>
    </span>
    <span class='post-icons'>
    <span class='item-control blog-admin pid-1598740620'>
    <a href='http://www.blogger.com/post-edit.g?blogID=4929692547831239344&postID=366770510419642006&from=pencil' title='Edit Post'>
    <img alt='' class='icon-action' height='18' src='http://img2.blogblog.com/img/icon18_edit_allbkg.gif' width='18'/>
    </a>
    </span>
    </span>
    <div class='post-share-buttons goog-inline-block'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-2'><span class='post-labels'>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-3'>
    <span class='post-location'>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Would there be a way to grab the link from here:

```
<h2>
<a href='http://www.beatmushroom.com/2012/05/logic-we-get-high.html'>Logic - We Get High</a>
</h2>
```

and then make the element:

```
    <div class="date-outer">
```

link to that?

since the rest of the post is inside that element it would make the post preview a link. They would then have to click on the background but I could probably make that work with z-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each `date-outer` element contains a single level 2 heading itself containing a single anchor:

```
$('.date-outer').each(function () {   
    $(this).click(function () {
        window.location = $('h2 a', this).attr('href');        
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WHd5d/1/

Comment: Hey I put it in like this into my code but it would not work: `<script type='text/javascript'>
$(&#39;.date-outer&#39;).each(function () {   
    $(this).click(function () {
        window.location = $(&#39;h2 a&#39;, this).attr(&#39;href&#39;);        
    });
});
</script>`

Comment: With respect @cohen, the above code works and the linked jsfiddle demonstrates this. Integrating with your site is something you'll have to tackle. If you can't, ask another question with a specific matter and I'm sure others will help.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the code. It does work what I meant was on my site it did not work. It actually made all date-outers a link to the first blog post on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to click on anything within the post and have it do what you want, then consider using the `*` selector

```
$('previewpost *').click(function() {
       doWhatever(); 
});
```